# Get the sibling value of a SQLITE value

Tags: javascript, sqlite, better-sqlite3

I have a SQLite Table:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| userID  | balance   | ledger    | lasttopup |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 | 90        |       780 |  12/10/18 |
|       2 | 180       |         0 |  4/11/18  |
|       3 | 270       |        12 |  13/10/18 |
|       4 | 360       |       109 |  11/10/18 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

And I am accessing the column **ledger** via:

```js
 const conn = new require('better-sqlite3')('../../data/databases/casino.sqlite3');     
const balances = conn.prepare(`SELECT * FROM "${msg.guild.id}"`).all().map(e => e.ledger)
```

And I want to get the userID which pertains to the respective ledger entry.
Visual:
[Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDUZK.png)

And then perform an action on the ledger value.

But I am unsure of how to retrieve the userID.

Any help will we appreciated!

```
[LIBRARIES]
DiscordJS
better-sqlite3
```

~Thanks

Comment: When you `SELECT *` from the table you will get the `userID`, but you throw it away when you only take the `ledger` in the map. You can keep both in the map with many variations of `.map(e => [e.userID, e.ledger])` or just access them directly without the map.